# QR CODE - how to?

Tags: android, split, qr-code

i want to hide the result from the QR CODE...
For example: ?re=123456789012&rr=
I just want to show 123456789012 and hide ?re= and &rr
Im reading and the people say use Split method,its that correct?

```
protected void  onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
     IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
     if(result != null){
         if(result.getContents()==null){
             Toast.makeText(this,"cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
        else{
             resultado.setText(result.getContents());
         }
     }
     else {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using substring function:-

**`function`**:-

```
private String getQR(String content)
{
 return content.substring(4,15);    
}
```

**`function implementation`**:-

```
     if(result.getContents()==null){
         Toast.makeText(this,"cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
    else{
         resultado.setText(getQR(result.getContents())); // <- <-
     }
```